# Is there a reduced de Broglie wavelength symbol for mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

I am working in a Jupyter notebook environment (which uses MathJax to typset math symbols in a Markup cell) writing mathematical physics equations and often related Python Numpy Sympy code in subsequent cells. It is driving me crazy that I cannot find a symbol for the so-called reduced de Broglie wavelength. It is a `\lambda` but with a short horizontal line (like the `$\hbar$` version of Planck's constant `$h$`) midway on the riser of `$\lambda$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be better if you can put a picture of what you want. BTW, have you tried `\textcrlambda`?

Comment: There is ƛ, if it's supported by the font. No “crossed lambda” is defined in Unicode, as far as I can see. It's not difficult to produce it in TeX, but Mathjax is just a different thing. A (bad) approximation might be `{\mkern2mu}\bar{}{\mkern-8mu}\lambda`

Comment: The link to the previous question will require some time to evaluate, but I immediately implemented the unicode insert to obtain a plausible barlamda, so am already happy. Thanks.